# Convert a numpy array to a list of numpy subarrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have the following variables

`values` and `diff_values`

I want diff_values to have the same format at values, here is the print out to the console

```
[ array([ -2.89100978e+01,   2.09523810e-02,   1.03174219e-01,
        -5.30000000e-01,  -5.30000000e-01])
 array([-13.47906113,   0.0288254 ,  -3.54654963,   0.08      ,   0.08      ])
 array([-74.79746139,  -0.07901799,  -5.44411026,  -0.78      ,  -0.78      ])
 ...,
 array([ -6.66326800e+00,   2.32902029e-01,  -7.10542736e-15,
         1.74234528e-03,   7.50000000e-01])
 array([ -7.93320153e+01,   1.35181758e-01,  -2.11119612e+00,
        -1.16156352e-03,  -5.00000000e-01])
 array([ -1.09462592e+02,  -1.61758096e-02,  -2.10215568e+00,
        -2.32312704e-03,  -1.00000000e+00])]



[[  6.21271154e+01   7.45228571e+01   5.36231884e+01   7.52100000e+01
    7.52100000e+01]
 [  3.32170176e+01   7.45438095e+01   5.37263626e+01   7.46800000e+01
    7.46800000e+01]
 [  1.97379565e+01   7.45726349e+01   5.01798130e+01   7.47600000e+01
    7.47600000e+01]
 ..., 
 [  1.81615120e+02   2.79861368e+01   5.58764070e+01   6.85322478e-02
    2.95000000e+01]
 [  1.02283105e+02   2.81213186e+01   5.37652109e+01   6.73706843e-02
    2.90000000e+01]
 [ -7.17948718e+00   2.81051428e+01   5.16630552e+01   6.50475572e-02
    2.80000000e+01]]
```

is there anyway I can remove the array() surrounding every list in every element in diff_values? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for accepting, you can also upvote the answer if you found it helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> x
array([[ 1.0683473 , -0.58759015,  0.02937106],
       [-1.03888421, -1.3840086 , -0.24847511],
       [-1.9586019 , -1.46525766,  0.71635925]])
```

---

IIUC, you can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [y for y in x] 
[array([ 1.0683473 , -0.58759015,  0.02937106]),
 array([-1.03888421, -1.3840086 , -0.24847511]),
 array([-1.9586019 , -1.46525766,  0.71635925])]
```